# Using x509 certificates to decrypt text with PowerShell that was encrypted with OpenSSL

Tags: powershell, ssl, encryption, openssl

I'm looking to set up a PowerShell script to decrypt secrets that were encrypted with the certificate public key in a Linux environment using OpenSSL.

The certificate with the private key to be used in the decryption is on the Windows Local Machine certificate store.

So far I’ve attempted to use
`[Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider].PrivateKey.Decrypt` to decrypt the bytes from the encrypted file but I get an error with the padding

```
$mycert.PrivateKey.Decrypt($bytes, $true)
Exception calling "Decrypt" with "2" argument(s): "Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding."
At line:1 char:1
+ $mycert.PrivateKey.Decrypt($bytes, $true)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CryptographicException
```

Could I get some pointers on how to solve this cryptographic exception?

The file containing the ciphertext was generated using the following sample openssl command in Linux:

```
echo " Secret Text" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey publickey.pem -pubin > secret.enc
```

It can be decrypted fine with OpenSSL but we always get the same error when trying PowerShell.

Comment: Are you trying to decrypt the file with the public or private key? Based on the error it seems like you are using the public, you must use the private key.

Comment: @Persistent13, the plaintext is encrypted with the public key while the ciphertext is decrypted with the private key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openssl rsautl`, without the `-oaep` flag, does PKCSv1_1.5 padding, which corresponds to a value of `false` in the `Decrypt` method you are calling.

Tangentally: If you have access to .NET 4.6 API in your powershell scope you would be better served by changing from casting `cert.PrivateKey` to `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to calling `cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()` and using the newer `RSA.Decrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1)`.  There are certificates/keys for which the old way doesn't work, and the new way does.

Comment: @bartonsjs. Thank you. I tried the $false argument on the Decrypt method before coming across your answer and that made it. I will modify the code to try the RSACryptoServiceProvider newer API. I don't think we have access to .NET 4.6 in the environment we use though, up to 4.5.2 only.

Answer (score 0):

$mycert.PrivateKey.Decrypt($bytes, $false) works when there is no padding specified in the encryption command with OpenSSL.